# SQL Server CTE For Each Date

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, recursion, left-join, common-table-expression

I am stuck at this point where I need to get a report for a screen in my project.

The user input is start date and end date...
I need the "closed task count" for each day between those values. If there are no tasks on some dates, the count should return "0". Here I am so far, but I really don't understand what I am doing wrong. Please help!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE APP.GET_TASK_ENTRY_ACTIVE_GRAPH 
(
    @START_DATE DATETIME,
    @END_DATE DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #TMP_TASK_VALS
(
    DATE_VALUE DATETIME,
    VAL INT
)

INSERT INTO #TMP_TASK_VALS
(
    DATE_VALUE, VAL
)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, TASK_CLOSING_DATE), COUNT(1) FROM APP.TASK_ENTRIES (NOLOCK)
WHERE TASK_CLOSING_DATE BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE
GROUP BY TASK_CLOSING_DATE
--ORDER BY TASK_CLOSING_DATE DESC

--SELECT * FROM #TMP_TASK_VALS

;WITH CTE_DAILY(DAY) AS
(
    SELECT @START_DATE AS DAY
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DAY + 1 FROM CTE_DAILY
    WHERE DAY < @END_DATE
)

SELECT CTE_DAILY.DAY, COUNT(VAL) FROM CTE_DAILY WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN #TMP_TASK_VALS WITH (NOLOCK) ON #TMP_TASK_VALS.DATE_VALUE = CTE_DAILY.DAY
GROUP BY CTE_DAILY.DAY

DROP TABLE #TMP_TASK_VALS

END
GO


/*
exec APP.GET_TASK_ENTRY_ACTIVE_GRAPH  '2015-08-10', '2015-08-16'
*/
```

The result is like, I have all the dates continuosly, but the value (count) is all zero.

Cheers.

Comment: @mxix I don't get NULL values anyway, I get 0's. How will this help?

Comment: Did you check if you are getting values in temp table?

Comment: Yeah @DarkKnight I have values, both dates and count values are just fine... I'm really lost haha.

Comment: Strange..i observed that you are converting TASK_CLOSING_DATE to datetime in first query,  but not while using BETWEEN. Can you also try to convert while joining with CTE?

Comment: @DarkKnight god bless you mate ahah! Found the problem, I was actually converting my date value to DATETIME which was supposed to be DATE only so I fixed it with `CONVERT(DATE, TASK_CLOSING_DATE)` phew! Cheers!!!!!!

Comment: I will add this as answer. please accept it, if you feel so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that you are converting `TASK_CLOSING_DATE` to datetime in first query, but not while using `BETWEEN`.I see some datatype mismatch. Please try to convert while joining with CTE too.

EDIT: As per OP's feedback the issues is with conversion of date and datetime fields. 
**OP's Comment :** Converting my DATETIME to DATE totally solved this

Comment: Converting my DATETIME to DATE totally solved this. Thanks for your help, it was basically a datetime issue. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to know. Cheers mate!